# R Loop function ignoring sequence increment

Tags: r, loops, increment

I need to append cos(i) to "result" for ALL incremented values of i, but this code only appends the non-incremented values.

```
result <- c()
for (i in seq(1,20,.1))
{
  print(cos(i))
  result[[i]] <- cos(i) 
}
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: See the output of `for (i in seq(1,20,.1)){ print(i) }`. You cannot have `result[19.4] <- cos(19.4)`. Indexing only works with integers. And you can avoid a `for` loop, as `cos` is vectorized. Just do `result <- cos(seq(1,20,.1))`.

Comment: The result vector is not equal to the printed values of cos(i). This code produces 200 elements for print(cos(i)), but the result vector contains 20.

Comment: Thanks Pascal! That works very well.